# Negative or Zero Value for Bandwidth using kde2d with for loop (MASS R Package)

Tags: r, for-loop, kde-plasma, mass

I am trying to run a two-dimensional kde using kde2d(MASS package) over multiple data frames  within a list.  When trying to run the loop, I get:

> Error in if (any(h <= 0)) stop("bandwidths must be strictly positive")
>   :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?  I've added sample data below as an example of what is being looped over.

> RTL_EOW DSL_SLS Avg_Wkly_Tmp PROXY_ID 
>      8/27/2016  0       78.65940641 1 
>      9/3/2016   2924    68.28091649 1 
>      9/10/2016  2656    69.3189759  1 
>      9/17/2016  5050    71.61575243 1 
>      9/24/2016  4254    73.85357591 1 
>      10/1/2016  5316    61.63126437 1 
>      10/8/2016  5582    57.10903173 1 
>      10/15/2016 5531    66.50587123 3 
>      10/22/2016 5046    53.08352004 3 
>      10/29/2016 8195    68.44048727 3 
>      11/5/2016  5535    52.66686763 3 
>      11/12/2016 6863    41.69310232 3 
>      11/19/2016 7976    38.96718858 3

```
K <- for (i in 1:length(Q)) {
Q[[i]] <- kde2d(Q[[i]]$Avg_Wkly_Tmp, 
Q[[i]]$Dsnl_Sls, n = 25, lims 
c(min(Q[[i]]$Avg_Wkly_Tmp), 
max(Q[[i]]$Avg_Wkly_Tmp), 
min(Q[[i]]$Dsnl_Sls), max(Q[[i]]$Dsnl_Sls)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have Q, but it looks like at least one element of it has zero range.

Comment: Thank you very much.  There were some small subsets within Q where all of the DSL_SLS values were 0, so min would equal max in those cases.  I didn't think explicitly about the calculation for h within MASS, but it makes sense the value would be 0 if the range was 0.  I will filter out those groups with zero range and see what happens.